# I use react-native-crypto and rn-nodeify libraries to interact with NFC tags in React Native but it doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native, tags, nfc

In the browser-based product, I use the aes-cmac library to process the tags. However, in the above application written in React Native, I copied the code of that library into a file to run because RN cannot use aes-cmac. But in that code copy there is the one-webcrypto library and its source code has the crypto library, and RN cannot read crypto. Is there any way to fix this error? I'm writing an android application that uses RN. Please help me
[image]

[image]